# iText PdfAConformanceException: PDF array is out of bounds

Tags: java, itext

i'm using iText 5.5.5 with Java5.

I'm trying to merge some PDF/A. when I got a "PdfAConformanceException: PDF array is out of bounds".

Trying to find error I find the "bad PDF" that cause the error and when I try to copy just it exception throw again. This error don't appear always, it appear just when this PDF/A is in the "job chain"; I tried with some other files and it's all fine. I cant share with you source PDF 'couse it's restricted.

That's my piece of code:

```
    _log.info("Start Document Merge");
    // Output pdf
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfACopy(document, bos, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1B);
    PageStamp stamp = null;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfContentByte content = null;
    int outPdfPageCount = 0;
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("Arial", BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    copyOutputIntents(reader, copy);
    // Loop over the pages in that document
    try {
        int numberOfPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
            PdfImportedPage pagecontent = copy.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            _log.debug("Handling page numbering [" + i + "]");
            stamp = copy.createPageStamp(pagecontent);
            content = stamp.getUnderContent();
            content.beginText();
            content.setFontAndSize(baseFont, Configuration.NumPagSize);
            content.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, String.format("%s %s ", Configuration.NumPagPrefix, i), Configuration.NumPagX, Configuration.NumPagY, 0);
            content.endText();
            stamp.alterContents();
            copy.addPage(pagecontent);
            outPdfPageCount++;
            if (outPdfPageCount > Configuration.MaxPages) {
                _log.error("Pdf Page Count > MaxPages");
                throw new PackageException(Constants.ERROR_104_TEXT, Constants.ERROR_104);
            }
        }
        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
        copy.createXmpMetadata();
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error("Error during mergin Document, skip");
        _log.debug(MiscUtil.stackToString(e));
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
```

That's the full stacktrace:

```
com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: PDF array is out of bounds.
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfA1Checker.checkPdfObject(PdfA1Checker.java:269)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAChecker.checkPdfAConformance(PdfAChecker.java:208)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.internal.PdfAConformanceImp.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfAConformanceImp.java:71)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3480)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.checkPdfIsoConformance(PdfWriter.java:3476)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray.toPdf(PdfArray.java:165)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(PdfDictionary.java:149)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray.toPdf(PdfArray.java:175)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(PdfDictionary.java:149)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:420)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:398)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:373)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:369)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:843)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.addToBody(PdfCopy.java:839)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.addToBody(PdfCopy.java:821)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyIndirect(PdfCopy.java:426)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyIndirect(PdfCopy.java:446)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyObject(PdfCopy.java:577)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyDictionary(PdfCopy.java:503)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyObject(PdfCopy.java:573)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyDictionary(PdfCopy.java:503)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyObject(PdfCopy.java:573)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyDictionary(PdfCopy.java:493)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.copyDictionary(PdfCopy.java:519)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy.addPage(PdfCopy.java:663)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfACopy.addPage(PdfACopy.java:115)
    at it.m2sc.engageone.documentpackage.generator.PackageGenerator.mergePDF(PackageGenerator.java:256)
```

Comment: I tried to make a Validation with http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx, at row #6 is written: "An array contains more than 8191 elements", should be a problem ?

Comment: That is exactly what iText complains about. That problem PDF, therefore, is not a valid PDF/A.

Comment: The limitation that an array can not have more than 8191 elements is a limitation that exists in ISO-19005-1. That limitation was removed in ISO-19005-2. Hence you have two options: either keep your requirement to be PDF/A-1 compliant and avoid creating arrays with more than 8191 elements; or change the requirement for PDF/A to be PDF/A-2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

In that specific case, the problem depends by a specific Font ( Gulim ) that is too big to be embedded in PDF/A-1 file. When that font was removed, everything war run fine.